# Xcode 8.2.1 editor shows no error when project is opened in a workspace

Tags: swift, xcode, workspace

I tried to integrate a project into a workspace together with a framework.

If I open a swift file with an (intentional) error inside the workspace, no error indicator is shown. The same swift file opened via the project does show the error.

What happened?

Here the snippet from the file with the correctly marked error, when opened via project:

```
class SomeClassName {
    var text: String {
        return 5 * r // error: use of unresolved identifier "r"
                   ^
    }
}
```

The same file opened in the mentioned workspace shows no error indicator. This problem also occurs with a simple syntax error and has nothing to do with the unresolved "r" which is just an example to show Xcodes problem with the error indicator.

Comment: Where is the object r declared? What type it is? You are trying to return the result of a multiplication as a String

Comment: already deleted all files under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: @Leo Dabus: r was never declared. This is a test snippet with an intentional error to show: Xcode has a problem to detect the error in the editor when opened via workspace

Answer (score 0):

Xcode determines dependencies between projects automatically. If it doesn't need to build a target for the currently selected scheme, it won't even try.